# How do you check if your running in either 64 bit or 32 bit for Delphi Android 10.3.3?

Tags: android, delphi, bit

Is there any documentation for Delphi Firemonkey Android 10.3.3 on checking to see if your running in either 32 bit or 64 bit on a Android device??

Answer from Dalija Prasnikar seems to work best:

```
var p: pointer;
begin
  if SizeOf(p) = 4 then
    showmessage('32 bit')
  else if SizeOf(p) = 8 then
    showmessage('64 bit');
```

I can't seem to get the other answers to work properly.

Comment: Fastest way is to check SizeOf(Pointer) 4 means 32 bit, 8 64 bit. Also, you cannot run 64bit if the device has 32bit OS.

Comment: My test device is running Android PIE

Comment: [Using TOSVersion to get Platform Information at Runtime in your FireMonkey Applications](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42188). See also [System.SysUtils.TOSVersion.Architecture](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.TOSVersion.Architecture)

Comment: Your code will only determine if the PROGRAM is 32-bit or 64-bit, not if the OS is 32-bit or 64-bit. So if you run a 32-bit PROGRAM on a 64-bit OS you will detect it as 32-bit (which may be what you want). This amounts to the same as my CPU32BITS compiler directive.

Answer (score 1):

```
{$IFDEF CPU32BITS }
  // 32-bit
{$ELSE }
  // 64-bit
{$ENDIF }
```

unless you mean if the Andoid OS is 32-bit or 64-bit (you can run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Android).

In that case

(assumning you already know you're running on Android)

```
USES System.SysUtils;

.
.
.

{$IFDEF CPU32BITS }
  IF TOSVersion.Architecture=TOSVersion.TArchitecture.arARM64 THEN
    // 64-bit
  ELSE
    // 32-bit
{$ELSE }
  // 64-bit
{$ENDIF }
```

Comment: When I target 32-bit platform debug it says its running 64 bit via your {$ELSE} clause and if I target 64-bit platform debug it also uses the {$ELSE} clause for 64-bit.  It also runs very very very slow if I target 64-bit platform for android. Any ideas?

Comment: @ElDiablo: I remembered the defined symbol wrong. Try again...

Comment: {$IFDEF CPU32BITS } TArchitecture.arARM64 unidentified, but the old one {$IFDEF USE32 } allows it to be indentified.

Comment: @ElDiablo: Ahh - TArchitecture is a class-local type identifier, so needs to be qualified. Fixed. Try again...